# Object Assignment Problems

Tags: java, oop, object, reference

I am having a problem when i assign objects, the object produces a reference duplicate that changes the value in original object.

This is my ***original object***

```
Node root = new Node();
root.filingState("input.txt");
```

After pushing my root in deque data structure, i retrieve it in a ***tmp variable***

```
Node tmp = deque.pop();
```

After that, i want my tmp variable to apply all the operators(up, down, left, right, which ever ones are possible) and check for the best result.

```
            if ( !tmp.goalTest(goal) ) {
                if ( tmp.ifDown() ) {
                    if ( !visited[tmp.getX()+1][tmp.getY()] ) {
                        newDown = new Node(tmp);
                        newDown.moveDown();
                    } else newDown = null;
                } // #EndOfDown!
                if ( tmp.ifUp() ) {
                    if ( !visited[tmp.getX()-1][tmp.getY()] ) {
                        newUp = new Node(tmp);
                        newUp.moveUp();
                    } else newUp = null;
                } // #EndOfUp!
                if ( tmp.ifLeft() ) {
                    if ( !visited[tmp.getX()][tmp.getY()-1] ) {
                        newLeft = new Node(tmp);
                        newLeft.moveLeft();
                    } else newLeft = null;
                } // #EndOfMoveLeft!
                if ( tmp.ifRight() ) {
                    if ( !visited[tmp.getX()][tmp.getY()+1] ) {
                        newRight = new Node(tmp);
                        newRight.moveRight();
                    } else newRight = null;
                } // #EndOfMoveRight!
            } else break;
```

***Operator functions***

```
public boolean ifUp ( ) { return y_blank-1 >= 0; }
public boolean ifDown ( ) { return y_blank+1 <= 4; }
public boolean ifLeft ( ) { return x_blank-1 >= 0; }
public boolean ifRight ( ) { return x_blank+1 <= 4; }

/* Movement functions
    Allows a user to move his blank on board
*/
public void moveUp ( ) {
    board[y_blank][x_blank] = board[y_blank-1][x_blank];
    board[y_blank-1][x_blank] = 'B';

    y_blank -= 1;
} // #EndOfMoveUp!

public void moveLeft ( ) {
    board[y_blank][x_blank] = board[y_blank][x_blank-1];
    board[y_blank][x_blank-1] = 'B';

    x_blank -= 1;
} // #EndOfMoveLeft!

public void moveRight ( ) {
    board[y_blank][x_blank] = board[y_blank][x_blank+1];
    board[y_blank][x_blank+1] = 'B';

    x_blank += 1;
} // #EndOfMoveRight!

public void moveDown ( ) {
    board[y_blank][x_blank] = board[y_blank+1][x_blank];
    board[y_blank+1][x_blank] = 'B';

    y_blank += 1;
} // #EndOfMoveDown!
```

newDown fails of 1st iteration since it doesn't fulfill the condition by my other Nodes pass the condition.

after my 1st newUp applies its operator, it changes the tmp Node aswell. Allowing newLeft, newRight to apply operators to the newly tmp Node values.

class ***Node.java***

```
private char[][] board;

private int x_blank = -1;
private int y_blank = -1;

private Node parent = null;

private Node up = null;
private Node left = null;
private Node right = null;
private Node down = null;

/* Constructor
    Allocates board to a 5x5 2D Array
*/
public Node ( ) { board = new char[5][5]; }
```

i tried creating a copy constructor but doesn't solve the problem.

***Copy constructor***

```
public Node ( Node tmp ) {
    this.board = new char[5][5];
    for ( int i=0; i<5; ++i ) {
        for ( int j=0; j<5; ++j ) this.board[i][j] = tmp.board[i][j];
    }

    this.x_blank = tmp.x_blank;
    this.y_blank = tmp.y_blank;

    if ( tmp.parent != null ) this.parent = tmp.parent;

    if ( tmp.up != null ) this.up = tmp.up;
    if ( tmp.left != null ) this.left = tmp.left;
    if ( tmp.right != null ) this.right = tmp.right;
    if ( tmp.down != null ) this.down = tmp.down;
}
```

so my question is that, how can i create an Object that can hold the values of some other Object, but when i apply the operator on the newly created object, it doesn't change the value of the original Object.

Answer (score 1):

Your copy constructor won't automatically be used on assignment of an instance of that object to a new variable. It is intended in Java that object assignments are by reference. You need to explicitly use your copy constructor in the assignment:

```
Node tmp = new Node(deque.pop());
```

Comment: tmp seems to be fine since it won't be altered anyways, newDown = new Node(tmp); and rest of new series doesn't actually create their own memory domain but refer to tmps original values.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to implement a clone function that will create a new object with the same value, then you will not change the value of the original Object.

for example:

```
clone(Node mynode){
    return new Node(mynode.getValue());
    }
```

Comment: You should give a more concrete example on how to use / implement clone correctly.

Comment: i really don't understand this part. what do you mean by clone? and i didn't even implement anything like getValue();

Comment: clone is a method of type object. from javadoc: clone() - Creates and returns a copy of this object.